# There are no subcategories in the selection - custom post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, taxonomy

everything is fine when creating a category:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL7wH.png

but when i want to create a post, i can't see the subcategories in the list:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n8NU.png

Can someone help me?

Comment: does this problem still occur if you switch to a default theme (like twenty twenty-one) and disable all plugins?

Comment: Please provide more details on what exactly you are doing there. Are these custom post types or default posts or pages? Are you talking about the default categories? It would be better to share the screenshots in english next time.